# Native resolution of 1366 by 768 on Sharp TV with home theater PC

Tags: tv, htpc

I have a Home theater PC setup connected to a Sharp 32 inch LC-32PD5X LCD TV.

I have spent some time trying to get a 1 to 1 pixel mapping at the native resolution of 1366 by 768 but have made little progress.

I have played around with the tool PowerStrip and have tried some obvious things (ie creating a new setup at 1366x768 at 50hz / 60hz) but no luck.

The best I can do is run the TV at 1280 by 720.  This looks ok for things like watching TV, DVD etc but results in what I would call "messy" fonts in Windows because the TV is converting pixels from 1280 by 720 to 1366 by 768.

I've read that 1366 by 768 is a pretend high definition mode that some TV manufacturers use to reduce costs.  Maybe this is just asking to much for a cheaper TV to do.

Overall, the TV is good enough for my needs, so just buying a proper 1080p TV is not an option (for a few years at least).

Comment: Can't you change resolution from Windows natively? Try doing this using the latest video card drivers. I've also had issues with my TV, but with overscan.

Comment: 1366x768 is a dairly common resolution for 16:10 widescreens.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your graphics card drivers and update them if necessary.

I've also a TV with 1366x768 and I'm able to set the TV resolution to 1360x768 (Windows and Linux) (I don't know why I lose 6 pixels, but hack, I don't care either). Also, the TV might be falsely recognized as generic or different model, so please check that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to set the picture size mode of your TV to something like "just scan". TVs normally work in overscan mode: the picture is resized to some value above 100% to cut off invisible areas and borders.

Maybe your TV does not support "just scan".